# How to get "shared with me' files in onedrive.live.com API?

Tags: onedrive

I know how to get list of my files (/me/skydrive/files). And I know filter, search, limit, offset query parameters. But there is no files in this list that were shared with me. Is it possible to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, when you perform the Login operation, you need to specify wl.contacts_skydrive as one of the required scopes, in addition to wl.signin and wl.skydrive.

Next, you ask for the contents of the folder "/me/skydrive/shared" and that gives you the information you are looking for.